# httpclient get gives ::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on using ng serve

Tags: angular, connection, serve

When I start the development Node server with ng serve.
and type in the below address, it works.

```
http://localhost:4200/login
```

However when I type in my username and password it gives me the below error in the console.

```
 OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/api/findCoinData?_id=5a1b2d9a6e915f5838ae5a50 
 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have tried

```
 ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

 ng serve --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true
```

Keep getting the same error, I have a feeling this problem happens due to the localhost setting, but changing it to the local IP didn't solve the issue.

Anyone has any idea what could be going wrong here?

All works when I use:

```
npm start
```

**app.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var cookieParser = require ('cookie-parser');
 var session = require ('express-session');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var morgan = require ('morgan');
 var mongo= require('mongodb');


 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var flash = require('connect-flash');
 var chat = require('./server/routes/chat');
 var connect = require('./models/user')
  //var cors = require('cors');
  connect.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
 var db = mongoose.connection;

  var passport = require ('passport');
  //var LocalStrategy = require ('passport-local').LocalStrategy;

   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


  var config = require ('./config/database');
 var engines = require('consolidate');


 var router = express.Router();
 var api = require('./server/routes/api');
 var app = express();
 app.use(logger('dev'));
 //app.use(cors());

// directories that are publicly accesible through the browser.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(morgan('dev'));
 app.use(session({
secret: 'secret123',
resave: true,
  saveUnitialized: true
  }));

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));

 //initialise always before session!
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
 app.use(flash());
 //set viewing engine

 app.use('/api', api);
 //app.get("/test", findAllMessages);
 app.get('*', (req, res) => {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));


   });

 // global variables flash
   app.use(function(req,res, next) {
res.locals.succes_msg = req.flash('succes_msg');
res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
res.locals.user = req.user || null;
next();
    });


   module.exports = app;
```

Comment: How do you setup your node server? Looks like CORS issue to me.

Comment: I added my app.js file not using cors atm, but maybe I should? I am not so sure what cors is used for yet.

Comment: Try turning on CORS. You'll need it.

Comment: Hi Chau, yes I turned it on, but doesn't change the problem unfotunately.

Comment: `app.options('*', cors())` try putting this right after `app.use(cors())`

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/cors docs on Cors

Comment: unfortunately nothing changes keep getting http://localhost:3000/api/findCoinData1?_id=any net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED which doesn't happen when starting server using npm start

Comment: oops I finally know why I get these messages....... I didn't start the server myself.... separately sigh..... apologies for my ignorance!

Comment: To clarify I didn't know you had to start npm start together with ng serve to be able to make it work. I thought just starting ng-serve would do both.